# {error: 'popup_closed_by_user'} while using react-google-login

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, react-google-login

I'm using react-google-login to login users using their Google account. When they finish logging in and being redirected to back i get an error in the console.

```
{error: 'popup_closed_by_user'}
```

This is my functions Below :

```
const onSuccess = (response) => {
   console.log('Login Successful', response)
}

const onFailure = (response) => {
   console.log('Login Failed', response)
}
```

My Google Button

```
<GoogleLogin
  clientId={clientId}
  render={renderProps => (
     <button onClick={renderProps.onClick} disabled= 
        {renderProps.disabled} className="btn mt-5 btn-google btn-user btn-block">
        <AiOutlineGoogle className='scIcons inline' /> Login with Google
     </button>
  )}
  buttonText="Login"
  onSuccess={onSuccess}
  onFailure={onFailure}
  cookiePolicy={'single_host_origin'}
  isSignedIn={true}
 />
```

Please I need help with this.

Comment: Im also facing same issue